# does javascript/jquery have an event model that you can create?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does jquery/javascript have any event model that you can attach to your objects?

Basically I want an object to have an event, and I want other objects to be able to subscribe to these events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at these:

[Custom events in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399867/custom-events-in-jquery)
[Custom jQuery event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040963/custom-jquery-event)

and here:

http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/04/custom-events-in-jquery-open-doors-to-complex-behaviors/

Comment: do you think YUI has a better way to do these things? more efficient?

Comment: @Blankman - I honestly wouldn't know, as I have never used YUI.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) function for custom events.